# Map GEO API Services

Tags: mapping, geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Does anyone know of a good even paid API for mapping to get GEO stuff.

I am really frustrated with google map giving poor results even though it beats all others.

I have tried so far.

- Google
- Yahoo
- BING
- Mapquest
- Multimap

Can anyone suggest other good services ?

Hope ya CAN !

Comment: Exactly what do you want the API to do?  Display information, or provide data?  Either way you might need to provide your own data if the best-in-breed web services don't do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've tried [ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/index.html) and [ArcView](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcview/index.html)?  This might be a little more than what you are looking for.

Comment: One for ArcGIS. But Not include data, he maybe want service with data.

Answer (score 1):

I can highly reccomend deCarta. They were the engine that Google and Yahoo started on. They are used by VZNavigator, Tmobile, Samsung, Nokia, and many other companies.

Their developer zone is free and you can it out there.

http://developer.decarta.com

Answer (score 0):

Check for Navdata website. Its very expensive but is cool and is used in almost GPS software.

Answer (score 0):

Try an API that can consume WMS and WFS, in addition to imagery.  I highly recommend a JavaScript API called [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/), which can consume Google, Bing, WMS, WFS, KML, and your own custom services.